# List Indexing using range() and len() not working

Tags: python, list, indexing

I am trying to parse through a data structure and I have used a for loop initializing a variable i and using the range() function. I originally set my range to be the size of the records: 25,173 but then I kept receiving an

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [63], line 41
     37         input_list.append(HOME_AVG_PTS)
     39     return input_list
---> 41 Data["AVG_PTS_HOME"]= extract_wl(AVG_PTS_HOME)

Cell In [63], line 28, in extract_wl(input_list)
     26         if i==25172:
     27             HOME_AVG_PTS[0]= HOME_AVG_PTS[0]/count
---> 28 elif int(Data(["TEAM_ID_AWAY"][i])) == const_home_team_id:
     29     if type(PTS_AWAY[i]) is int:
     30         count+= 1

IndexError: list index out of range
```

So I tried changing my for loop to be in the range of the function with the issue i.e.

```
for i in range(len(Data["TEAM_ID_AWAY"])):
```

But I keep receiving the same error still

The Data variable holds the contents of a csv file which I have used the panda module to read and put into Data. You can assume all the column headers I have used are valid and furthermore that they all have range 25173.
[Here is an image showing the range and values for the Data["TEAM_ID_HOME"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZWkHQ.png)

```
AVG_PTS_HOME = []

def extract_wl(input_list):
    for j in range(25173):
        const_season_id = Data["SEASON_ID"][j]
        #print(const_season_id)
        const_game_id = int(Data["GAME_ID"][j])
        #print(const_game_id)
        const_home_team_id = Data["TEAM_ID_HOME"][j]
        #print(const_home_team_id)

        #if j==10:
            #break
        
        print("Iteration #", j)
        print(len(Data["TEAM_ID_AWAY"]))
        count = 0
        HOME_AVG_PTS=[0.0]

        for i in range(len(Data["TEAM_ID_AWAY"])):
            if (int(Data["GAME_ID"][i]) < const_game_id and int(Data["SEASON_ID"][i]) == const_season_id):
                if int(Data["TEAM_ID_HOME"][i]) == const_home_team_id:
                    if type(PTS_HOME[i]) is int:
                        count+= 1
                        HOME_AVG_PTS[0]+= PTS_HOME[i]
                        if i==25172:
                            HOME_AVG_PTS[0]= HOME_AVG_PTS[0]/count
                elif int(Data(["TEAM_ID_AWAY"][i])) == const_home_team_id:
                    if type(PTS_AWAY[i]) is int:
                        count+= 1
                        HOME_AVG_PTS[0]+= PTS_AWAY[i]
                        if i==25172:
                            HOME_AVG_PTS[0]= float(HOME_AVG_PTS[0]/count)
                
    
        print(HOME_AVG_PTS)
        input_list.append(HOME_AVG_PTS)

    return input_list

Data["AVG_PTS_HOME"]= extract_wl(AVG_PTS_HOME)
```

Can anyone point out why I am having this error or help me resolve it? In the meantime I think I am going to just create a separate function which takes a list of all the AWAY_IDs and then parse through that instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hardcoding the length of the list is likely to lead to bugs down the line even if you're able to get it all working correctly with a particular data set.  Iterating over the lists directly is much less error-prone and generally produces code that's easier to modify.  If you want to iterate over multiple lists in parallel, use the `zip` function.  For example, this:

```
    for j in range(25173):
        const_season_id = Data["SEASON_ID"][j]
        const_game_id = int(Data["GAME_ID"][j])
        const_home_team_id = Data["TEAM_ID_HOME"][j]
        # do stuff with const_season_id, const_game_id, const_home_team_id
```

can be written as:

```
    for (const_season_id, game_id, const_home_team_id) in zip(
        Data["SEASON_ID"], Data["GAME_ID"], Data["TEAM_ID_HOME"]
    ):
        const_game_id = int(game_id)
        # do stuff with const_season_id, const_game_id, const_home_team_id
```

The `zip` function will never give you an `IndexError` because it will automatically stop iterating when it reaches the end of any of the input lists.  (If you want to stop iterating when you reach the end of the *longest* list instead, there's `zip_longest`.)

Answer (score 0):

```
elif int(Data(["TEAM_ID_AWAY"][i])) == const_home_team_id
```

Your parentheses are in the wrong place.

You have parentheses around `(["TEAM_ID_AWAY"][i])`, therefore it is trying to take the i'th index of the single-element list `["TEAM_ID_AWAY"]`.

You want `Data["TEAM_ID_AWAY"][i]`, not `Data(["TEAM_ID_AWAY"][i])`.